# Perl: How to turn array into nested hash keys

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I need to convert a flat list of keys into a nested hash, as follow:

> my $hash = {};
>
> my @array = qw(key1 key2 lastKey Value);
>
> ToNestedHash($hash, @array);

Would do this:

> $hash{'key1'}{'key2'}{'lastKey'} = "Value";

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
sub to_nested_hash {
    my $ref   = \shift;  
    my $h     = $$ref;
    my $value = pop;
    $ref      = \$$ref->{ $_ } foreach @_;
    $$ref     = $value;
    return $h;
}
```

Explanation:

- Take the first value as a hashref
- Take the last value as the value to be assigned
- The rest are keys.
- Then create a *SCALAR* reference to the base hash.
- Repeatedly:

  - Dereference the pointer to get the hash (first time) or autovivify the pointer as a hash
  - Get the hash slot for the key
  - And assign the scalar reference to the hash slot.
  - ( Next time around this will autovivify to the indicated hash ).
- Finally, with the reference to the innermost slot, assign the value.

We know:

- That the occupants of a hash or array can only be a scalar or reference.
- That a reference is a scalar of sorts. (`my $h = {}; my $a = [];`).
- So, \$h->{ $key } is a reference to a scalar slot on the heap, perhaps autovivified.
- That a "level" of a nested hash can be autovivified to a hash reference *if* we address it as so.

It might be more explicit to do this:

```
foreach my $key ( @_ ) { 
    my $lvl = $$ref = {};
    $ref    = \$lvl->{ $key };
}
```

But owing to repeated use of these reference idioms, I wrote that line totally as it was and tested it before posting, without error.

As for alternatives, the following version is "easier" (to think up)

```
sub to_nested_hash {
    $_[0] //= {};
    my $h     = shift;
    my $value = pop;
    eval '$h'.(join '', map "->{\$_[$i]}", 0..$#_).' = $value';
    return $h;
}
```

But about 6-7 times slower.

Comment: Could you add an explanation, please?

Comment: +1 I didn't think to autovivify a hash element by taking a reference to it

Comment: @Borodin, it was a *god-send* when I found it would work. I was using some multi-level hash transforms to do some feed processing and it sped up my most-used routines 600%-1000%.

Comment: Made a minor change so `my $h; to_nested_hash($h, @keys, $val);` works.

Comment: Made a minor change so keys such as `foo bar` and `system("rm -rf /")` work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon this code is better - more amenable to moving into a class method, and optionally setting a value, depending on the supplied parameters.  Otherwise the selected answer is neat.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use YAML;

my $hash = {};

my @array = qw(key1 key2 lastKey);
my $val = [qw/some arbitrary data/];

print Dump to_nested_hash($hash, \@array, $val);
print Dump to_nested_hash($hash, \@array);
sub to_nested_hash {
    my ($hash, $array, $val) = @_;
    my $ref   = \$hash;
    my @path = @$array;
    print "ref: $ref\n";
    my $h     = $$ref;
    $ref      = \$$ref->{ $_ } foreach @path;
    $$ref     = $val if $val;
    return $h;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thxs for the good stuff!!!

I did it the recursive way:

```
sub Hash2Array
{
  my $this = shift;
  my $hash = shift;

  my @array;
  foreach my $k(sort keys %$hash)
  {
    my $v = $hash->{$k};
    push @array,
      ref $v eq "HASH" ? $this->Hash2Array($v, @_, $k) : [ @_, $k, $v ];
  }

  return @array;
}
```

It would be interesting to have a performance comparison between all of these solutions...

Answer (score 0):

Made a better version of axeman's i think. Easier to understand without the -> and the \shift to me at least. 3 lines without a subroutine.

With subroutine

```
sub to_nested_hash {
    my $h=shift;
    my($ref,$value)=(\$h,pop);
    $ref=\%{$$ref}{$_} foreach(@_);
    $$ref=$value;
    return $h;
}

my $z={};
to_nested_hash($z,1,2,3,'testing123');
```

Without subroutine

```
my $z={};

my $ref=\$z; #scalar reference of a variable which contains a hash reference
$ref=\%{$$ref}{$_} foreach(1,2,3); #keys
$$ref='testing123'; #value

#with %z hash variable just do double backslash to get the scalar reference
#my $ref=\\%z;
```

Result:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '1' => {
                   '2' => {
                            '3' => 'testing123'
                          }
                 }
        };
```

Comment: The method without the subroutine didn't compile for me. The `$ref=\%{$$ref}{$_} foreach(1,2,3);` has a problem.