# Ruby: Turn array into nested pointer

Tags: arrays, ruby, pointers, hash, nested

Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505100/perl-how-to-turn-array-into-nested-hash-keys), but in Ruby.

I have a nested hash (below is a NON literal example), and I have an array that points to my deepest child value:

```
ab0:
  ad1:
    ab0:
      ad1: {}
ad1:
  ab0:
    ad1:
      ab0: {}
```

The array that points to the last key "ab0" is [1,0,0,0]. I would like to use this array to traverse the hash by pointing to hash[1][0][0][0].

I will be using this hopefully to get each key used on the path to the child in question. My result should be:

```
keysUsed(hash, [1,0,0,0]) = [hash.keys[1], hash.keys[1].keys[0], hash[1].keys[0].keys[0]]
```

Comment: You hash is not valid Ruby code. Besides, why should `hash.keys[1]` refer to `:ab0` and not `:ad1`?

Comment: Maybe you could choose a different example hash, it's quite confusing to have repeating key names.

Comment: Why is the last `0` ignored? Shouldn't there be `hash[1].keys[0].keys[0].keys[0]` at the end? Are the keys hashes as well?

Comment: And last but not least: what's your expected result? For an input of `[1,0,0,0]`, you have given an array with 3 (why?) elements: `hash.keys[1]`, `hash.keys[1].keys[0]` and `hash[1].keys[0].keys[0]` but only the first one produces a result. Maybe the second element should be `hash[hash.keys[1]].keys[0]`? Please clarify.

Comment: The linked question creates a nested Hash from an Array. If I understand it right, you want just the opposite. I'm not even sure, since your title also describes the opposite of your question.

Comment: @Stefan my apologies for not being clear. The code was meant to be an example, and I did not specify "require 'yaml'" and that the has above is a valid YAML representation of a Ruby hash. Its much easier to read and understand the nesting. In this case, hash.keys[1] refers to the second position of the keys to the whole hash, which are [ab0, ad1]. Eric Duminil has a great answer below!

Comment: @Stefan, you are correct in your third comment. I miswrote that in the question. The first element would be Hash.keys[1], the second element would be Hash[1].keys[0], the third element would be Hash[1][0].keys[0]. That would return to you a descending path as an array [ad1, ab0, ad1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Array to nested Hash

Here's an answer to the question in your title and the link you provided :

```
def to_nested_hash(array)
  array.reverse.inject { |h, k| { k => h } }
end

hash1 = to_nested_hash([:a, :b, :c, :d])
#=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>:d}}}
```

## Nested Hash to Array

```
def path_from_nested_hash(hash, indices)
  path = []
  indices.inject(hash){ |h, i|
    case h
    when Hash
      path << h.keys[i]
      h.values[i] || {}
    when Array
      path << h[i]
      h[i]
    else
      path << h
    end
  }
  path
end

path_from_nested_hash( hash1.merge(hash2), [0,0,0,0])
# [:a, :b, :c, :d]
path_from_nested_hash( hash1.merge(hash2), [1,0,0,0])
# [:e, :f, :g, :h]
path_from_nested_hash( hash1.merge(hash2), [1,1,0,0])
# [:e, nil, nil, nil]
```

Comment: thank you! My apologies that the question wasn't super clear. However, your answer did the trick. I can now give a Hash and a Pointer array, and get an array of keys traversed to get to the pointer.