# Perl :Not a HASH reference while creating nested hash from multi dimension arrays

Tags: perl, hash

I want to create a nested hash by reading values from multi dimention arrays which are separated by -> e.g.

```
Array 1: key1->key2->key3->value
Array 2: key1->key2->value
Array 3: key1->value
```

When key has value and sub keys as well e.g. key2 has value and another key key3 as well then get error "Not a HASH reference ".Seem it is overwriting previous hash and considering it array.

Help is appreciated. I have tried to debug and print the values of variables and output by using dumper module and see that it is ARRAY reference and not hash.

in order to repro, please create .txt files e.g. from 1 to 3.txt in any folder and have below content in these files 1.txt : /*TEST-TAG = ABC->DEF->fma->GHI*/ 2.txt:/*TEST-TAG = ABC->DEF->fma 3.txt:/*TEST-TAG = ABC->DEF and then have in perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines=`grep -R 'TEST-TAG =' <FOLDER where .txt files present>`;
my $hash;

#parse the lines which has pattern /\*TEST-TAG = ABC->DEF->fma->GHI\*/
foreach (@lines)
    {
    print "line is $_\n";

    my($all_cat) = $_ =~ /\=(.*)\*\//;
    print "all cat is $all_cat\n";

    my($testname) = $_ =~ /\/.*\/(.*)\./;
    print "testname is $testname\n";

    if (!$all_cat eq "") {
        $all_cat =~ s/ //g;
        my @ts = split(',', $all_cat);
        print "ts is @ts\n";
        my $i;
        foreach (@ts) {
            my @allfeat = split('->',$_);
            my $count =  scalar @allfeat;
            for ($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++) {
                my @temparr = @allfeat[$i..$count-1];
                print "temparr is @temparr\n";
                push @temparr, $testname;
                ToNestedHash($hash, @temparr);
            }
        }
    }
}
sub ToNestedHash {
        my $ref   = \shift;
        print "sandeep in ref $ref\n";
        print "sandeep in ref", ref($ref), "\n";
        my $h     = $$ref;
        print "sandeep h $h\n";
        my $value = pop;
        print "sandeep value is $value\n";
        print "sandeep array is @_\n";
        print "refrence",  ref($h), "\n";
        foreach my $i (@_) {
        print " before INDEX $i\n";
        print Dumper($ref);
        $ref =\$$ref->{ $i };
        print "after INDEX $i\n";
        print Dumper($ref);
        }
        if (!isinlist(\@{$$ref},$value)) {
            push @{$$ref}, $value;
        }
        return $h;
    }
    # If element exists in the list
    sub isinlist {
        my ($aref, $key) = ($_[0], $_[1]);

        foreach my $elem (@$aref){
            if ($elem eq $key) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I get this output with debug prints

```
line is File.txt:/*TEST-TAG = ABC->DEF->fma->GHI*/

all cat is  ABC->DEF->fma->GHI
testname is hmma_884_row_row_f16_f16
ts is ABC->DEF->fma->GHI
temparr is ABC DEF fma GHI
sandeep in ref REF(0x12a1048)
sandeep in refREF
sandeep h HASH(0x12a09a0)
sandeep value is hmma_884_row_row_f16_f16
sandeep array is ABC DEF fma GHI
refrenceHASH

REF
temparr is DEF fma GHI
sandeep in ref REF(0x12a1048)
sandeep in refREF
sandeep h HASH(0x12a09a0)
sandeep value is hmma_884_row_row_f16_f16
sandeep array is DEF fma GHI
refrenceHASH

REF
temparr is fma GHI
sandeep in ref REF(0x12a1048)
sandeep in refREF
sandeep h HASH(0x12a09a0)
sandeep value is hmma_884_row_row_f16_f16
sandeep array is fma GHI
refrenceHASH
Not a HASH reference at createjson.pl line 80.
```

problematic line is  `$ref =\$$ref->{$_} foreach (@_);`

Comment: `Global symbol "@lines" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @lines"?) at .code.tio line 6.`

Comment: it was there in my code but I did not add it in sample.Added it now.

Comment: `testname is hmma_884_row_row_f16_f16` Where does this come from?

Comment: you can replace File.txt with hmma_884_row_row_f16_f16.txt

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add a representative input file. Also, you can inspect what your data actually is by using [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) and looking at the data you actually have.

Comment: `if (!$all_cat eq "")` is an odd construct. Why go out of your way to *make it sound* like you're testing for emptiness when you're actually - in a roundabout way - testing truthness? `!$all_cat` is evaluated first, giving a truth value, that will be converted to a string (either "1" or "", the empty string) for string comparison. It's clearer to say just `if ($all_cat)` if you want truthness or `if ($all_cat ne '')` if you want non-empty.

Comment: Or even `if (not $all_cat eq '')` - `not` has a considerably lower precendence than `!`. Perldoc `perlcheat` is handy for double-checking the precedence rules.

Comment: Your test output (in both runs) includes `testname is hmma_884_row_row_f16_f16`. When I run your code, I get `testname is` and a warning about using an uninitialised value. `$testname` is set using this code - `my($testname) = $_ =~ /\/.*\/(.*)\./` and I can see no way to get the results you claim to see from the data and code that you have given us. I'm happy to help here, but unless you show us code and data that actually exhibit the behaviour that you describe, I would just be guessing and that would be a waste of my time.

Comment: Isn't `if (!$all_cat eq "")` just a deliberately confusing way to write `if (length $all_cat)` ?

Comment: Also, there's a lot of very confusing reference syntax in here. I'm not sure if the code was written by someone who was very clever or someone who wasn't anywhere near as clever as they thought they were :-)

Comment: you are correct .code was copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505100/perl-how-to-turn-array-into-nested-hash-keys/54086289#54086289

Comment: @Dave Cross ,please create .txt files e.g. from 1 to 3.txt in any folder and have below content in these files   1.txt :  /*TEST-TAG = ABC->DEF->fma->GHI*/  2.txt:ABC->DEF->fma 3.txt:ABC->DEF and then have in perl script  my @lines = `grep -R 'TEST-TAG =' <foldername>

Comment: @sandeepnagori: If you want to correct your example, please do it by editing your question - not by adding it as a comment.

Comment: @dave Cross,I have edited the question.

Comment: @sandeepnagori: Please take a closer look at your code. The syntax highlighting is there for a reason. You have missed something (probably a closing backtick). Programming is about attention to detail.

Comment: @Dave Cross,Thanks for pointing.Fixed the same

Comment: @melpomene Can you please try now as i have edited the question.Thanks

Comment: if (!$all_cat eq "") is effectively equal to if ($all_cat ne ""), but it gets there via a rather disconcerting route.  It's the sort of thing you'd put in your code if you wanted to really bother a bunch of perl programmers when they read it.  I'd really recommend you fix that to some version that's less obtuse.  My preferred would be if (defined $all_cat and length $all_cat), but that's probably just me.

Answer (score 2):

After sleeping on it, I realized where you were trying to go with this more.  Your issue of concern is the fact that you're trying to use some hash values as both arrays and as hashes.  There are two approaches to dealing with this.  Detect and handle it, or avoid it.  The avoid code is much cleaner, so I'll show that.

As I mentioned in my original answer, I'm not sure what you had in mind for the 'Dumper' lines, but Data::Dump is probably a useful replacement for what you were using, with less complication than the Data::Dumper module that I was thinking you were somehow managing to use.  I also chose to still provide a replacement for your file name regex, as I still don't want to bother with a full path name.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

my @lines = `grep -R 'TEST-TAG =' foo`;
my $hash;

$| = 1; # keep STDOUT and STDERR together

#parse the lines which has pattern /\*TEST-TAG = ABC->DEF->fma->GHI\*/
foreach (@lines) {
    print "line is $_\n";

    my($all_cat) = $_ =~ /\=(.*)\*\//;
    print "all cat is $all_cat\n";

    my($testname) = $_ =~ /(?:.*\/)?(.*?)\./;
    print "testname is $testname\n";

    if ($all_cat ne "") {
        $all_cat =~ s/ //g;
        my @ts = split(',', $all_cat);
        print "ts is @ts\n";
        my $i;
        foreach (@ts) {
            my @allfeat = split('->',$_);
            my $count =  scalar @allfeat;
            for ($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++) {
                my @temparr = @allfeat[$i..$count-1];
                print "temparr is @temparr\n";
                push @temparr, $testname;
                ToNestedHash($hash, @temparr);
            }
        }
    }
}

sub ToNestedHash {
    my $ref   = \shift;
    print "sandeep in ref ";
    dd $ref;
    my $h     = $$ref;
    print "sandeep h ";
    dd $h;
    my $value = pop;
    print "sandeep value is $value\n";
    print "sandeep array is @_\n";
    print "refrence",  ref($h), "\n";
    foreach my $i (@_) {
        print " before INDEX $i\n";
        dd $ref;
        $ref =\$$ref->{ $i };
        print "after INDEX $i\n";
        dd $ref;
    }
    $ref =\$$ref->{ _ARRAY };
    if (!isinlist(\@{$$ref},$value)) {
        push @{$$ref}, $value;
    }
    return $h;
}
# If element exists in the list
sub isinlist {
    my ($aref, $key) = ($_[0], $_[1]);

    foreach my $elem (@$aref){
        if ($elem eq $key) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This line $ref =\$$ref->{ _ARRAY }; did the magic.Thanks @Ed.